# scrollTop inside position Fixed

Tags: jquery

I am facing an issue where I need to use scrollTop inside a div thats position fixed and overflow-y.
I did see a post
[Using scrollTop inside of a fixed element with overflow-y:scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144191/using-scrolltop-inside-of-a-fixed-element-with-overflow-yscroll)

The issue I have is, the error element to which I have to scroll is positioned inside a content that is relative positioned. So this code does not work

My fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5446a6ds/2/

If I remove the parent with relative positioning, it works, but I cannot do that.
Also the error may be positioned anywhere within the content that is relatively positioned., so scrolling to content is also not an option.

HTML

```
<div id="relativeDad">
    <div id="containerParent">
    <div id="containerChild">
        <section id="content">
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
             this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
            <p class="form-error-msg">
Please provide missing information in the fields highlighted below.</p>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
             this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
             this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                this is a form<br>
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="date" id="dateOfBirth" required="">
                    <input type="password">
                </fieldset>
                <button id="button1">button</button>


        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>

Javascript
$("#button1").on("click", function(){

    var position = $(".form-error-msg").position().top +             $("#containerChild").scrollTop();
$("#containerChild").animate({scrollTop: position});
});

CSS
#relativeDad {
    position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
}
#containerParent {
    position: fixed;
    background-color:blue;
     height: 100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}
#containerChild {
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
 height: 100%;

}

#content {
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're adding too much to position. Having

```
var position = $(".form-error-msg").position().top;
```

is sufficient because .position is relative to the offset parent already so you're only scrolling within #containerChild

Here's an updated fiddle. I've added a paragraph before and changed the height to 80% to demonstrate the relative calculation.

http://jsfiddle.net/5446a6ds/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot. This does work, but then when i add content in between, http://jsfiddle.net/5446a6ds/4/  it scrolls somewhere above the error message

Comment: @keerti there are 2 issues. First, .position detects the element's position relative to its closest parent with position: relative set: you have to remove position: relative from #content. So now it'll calculate .form-error-msg's position relative to #relativeParent. But since you have a paragraph outside of #relativeParent it won't take into account. Everything should sit inside the most immediate container. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5446a6ds/5/